# Are Sikhs considered idolatry

Tags: avodah-zarah

According to Sikhism, Guru Nanak was the first Sikh prophet. He disappeared in a river for three days and returned to spread a message.   After his death Sikhs built The Golden Temple at Amritsar, which has four doors, so all peoples of faith may enter since Sikhism is irrespective of their religion, caste, color, or creed, and status.

Sikhs are not Hindus. They are not polytheists. They are monotheists. They say:

> "G-d is formless, pervading everything. He is beyond space and time.
> There is One G-d whose name is Truth. G-d has no form, no country, and
> no religion."

Thus, the Sikh faith seems to hold that there is only one G-d. Do we consider them idolatry, or are they close to Muslims in the sense that they worship one G-d, they are not Avodah Zarah? And if so, are Jews allowed to worship in the Golden Temple?

Comment: https://outorah.org/p/2770/